# symfony2 fatal error in form declaration

Tags: forms, symfony

When I visit my browser this is what i get:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Ecs\CrmBundle\Form\Parts\DepartmentSelectionType::getDefaultOptions() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::getDefaultOptions() in C:\wamp\www\crm\src\Ecs\CrmBundle\Form\Parts\DepartmentSelectionType.php on line 41
```

And the file that it is referencing there is found below:

```
<?php

namespace Ecs\CrmBundle\Form\Parts;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;


class DepartmentSelectionType extends AbstractType {
    private $canSeeAll = false;

    public function __construct($canSeeAll = false)
    {
        $this->canSeeAll = $canSeeAll;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('department', 'entity',
                array(
                    'class' => "EcsAgentManagerBundle:EmployeeDepartment",
                    'required' => false,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'label' => "Department"))
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Ecs\AgentManagerBundle\Entity\EmployeeDepartment',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ecs_crmbundle_departmentselectiontype';
    }
}
```

is the file that it is referencing... Any ideas on what the issue can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the FormTypeInterface has changed in Symfony 2.1.

[`getDefaultOptions`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormTypeInterface.php#L80) no longer takes an argument.

From the [UPGRADE-2.1 document](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md):

---

> The methods getDefaultOptions() and getAllowedOptionValues() of form
>   types no longer receive an option array.
>
> You can specify options that depend on other options using closures
>   instead.

**Before**:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    $defaultOptions = array();

    if ($options['multiple']) {
        $defaultOptions['empty_data'] = array();
    }

    return $defaultOptions;
}
```

**After**:

```
public function getDefaultOptions()
{
    return array(
        'empty_data' => function (Options $options, $previousValue) {
            return $options['multiple'] ? array() : $previousValue;
        }
    );
}
```